# Multiple Search in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
NSString *labelText = @"Choose a topic from the left to find answers for your questions about iPhone. For the latest downloads, manuals, and other resources for iPhone, choose an option below.";
NSLog(@"Label Text:--->%@",labelText);
```

So my issue is that I want to search iPhone text wherever is display in above nsstring and also get position if possible so please give me any idea or any link to develop this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it here: (`NSLog` will print indexes of your `substring` positions in `source` string)

```
- (void)findAllLocationsOfString:(NSString *)substring sourceString:(NSString *)source
{
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [source length]);
    NSRange place = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    while (searchRange.location < [source length])
    {
        place = [source rangeOfString:substring options:NSLiteralSearch range:searchRange];
        if (place.location != NSNotFound) NSLog(@"found here : %d", place.location);
        searchRange.location = place.location + place.length;
        searchRange.length = [source length] - searchRange.location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and any idea to set add button frame on getting search substring

Comment: Ask new questions in new topics, please